# what is the purpose and meaning of "://" and how is it used

Tags: network

When going to a website we see https://example.com, I know the purpose of http and https protocols, but what is the purpose of "://" after? I know "\" is being used for directories, but still dont explain the ":"

Comment: '\' is used for directories in Windows only, I think what you meant is `/` .

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

':' separates the protocol and the resource.

The basic idea is that a path starting with '/' indicates the root of a device/volume etc. So, '//' is used to indicate the "top of the network", followed by the server name.

In a URL, this scheme can be used to indicate relative paths on the same resource, e.g. *http:/index.html* for a file in the root of the current server, or *http:pic.gif* for a file in the same directory on the current server.

Microsoft Windows generally uses backslashes ('\' and '\\') instead of the forward slashes because PC DOS 1.0 already used '/' as a commandline option indicator before subdirectories were introduced in PC DOS 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the explanation on this Wikipedia page.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL [Under 'Syntax']

Comment: to be more precise, it's only a convention used to separate the different parts that make up an URL : `$protocol://$host/$directory[:$port]` .

Comment: @schaiba The `[:$port]` bit needs to be following the `$host`. ;-)